# Woman speaks rudely with a male colleague in the elevator

Tags: unprofessional-behavior

We work in a building with 5-6 different companies sharing 3 elevators. One day, one of my male colleague and I entered into a lift which was 3/4th filled. By mistake, my male colleague's forearm touched one of the women and he adjusted immediately. But, she responded rudely to him and said something nasty.  My colleague and I were not happy with what happened.  Yes, he was hurt and he said the same after coming out of the elevator.

She is not a colleague and we have no idea which company she works for.

I was wondering, what could I have possibly said to him to pacify him or infact, to that woman?

Comment: You may also ask "what could I have said to that woman"...

Comment: @Solar Mike, edited.

Comment: please add if it was just nasty or if it was an insult, also if the woman in question works in the same or a different company and if you know the company she works in.

Comment: @sascha I felt she could have ignored that unintentional touch and her reaction was unnecessary. Edited the post.

Comment: You're spending too much time thinking about something so minor. Besides, you can not really control what others say or think of you (or your colleague).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about navigating the workplace. Probably best ask this in "Interpersonal Skills".

Comment: Some background to consider. There are men who enjoy pretending to make accidental contact with a woman in crowded public situations. It seems to be some mix of sex and a power play, enjoying forcing the woman to give the man the benefit of the doubt if she cannot be sure the contact was deliberate. Her experiences may affect how a woman reacts to genuinely accidental contact.

Comment: Too vague. What is the question, what did she say, why was it relevant, if you are never going to see her why do anything? If you don't work with her how is it even workplace related?

Answer (score 6):

**In the moment, apologize and let it go.** It was likely a misunderstanding.

**Let your colleague know you observed what happened, that they didn't do anything wrong, and that it's probably best to let it go.** Weird interactions happen from time to time, it's just the nature of working in social organizations. Your colleague will appreciate the validation that they behaved appropriately, but nothing more needs to be done.

---

**If this individual repeatedly treats others rudely or disproportionately, consider offering them some feedback.** The gender or employer of an individual doesn't change the behavioral norms or standards of your workplace - undesirable behavior is unwelcome regardless of who the actor is.

**You don't need to work with someone to offer feedback** - if this is someone you occasionally run in to in the elevator, and have similar interactions, speak up.

However, **you should be thoughtful and careful in delivering feedback.** Be careful to not draw distinctions along gender. Focus on the specific behavior you observed and the impact it had on you - never presume what the recipient of your feedback may have been thinking or trying to communicate.

Answer (score 1):

Just say "I think that was uncalled for - some people are idiots - sorry you have to put up with such crap." to your colleague. Depending on your mood and aggressiveness you can say that with the other person in reach or not.

If you feel very aggressive, the next time you see the woman in the elevator and are with a male colleague, point ironically out to him to keep a safety distance.

Comment: I prefer quite much your approach of the 1st paragraph, the 2nd not so much, especially in a work setting. It is a small world, you never know when you are crossing paths with that person tomorrow, much less with someone working in the same building. The 2nd paragraph feels childish. +1 for the first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Simply tell him that, statistically, there is always going to be a certain percentage of fools, and there's no point in worrying about how they react; all he should be worrying is if he did everything from his side correctly.

If he did, and the other person still reacts in a rude manner, it's that person's problem, not his.

Of course, in places and times with inane laws and courts, this answer might need some modifications...